# Raster reclass can't load remap table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, reclassify

I have a 2017 Land Use raster of the US, shown below

[image: Land use-Land Cover map of the US]

that I'm trying to reclassify. It has 256 different values right now and my plan is to only have nine at the end - a few crops I care about and 'other'. I made a table in Excel that I'm trying to import into the reclassify tool so I won't have to change 256 values in ArcMap by hand.

The table is, for example,formatted like this:

[image: Formatted like this all the way to the end.]

And so on. When I try to load the table into the reclassify tool, it says "error, couldn't load table" and nothing else. I've tried it as a .xslx and a .txt file

Additionally, when I try loading the table to my ArcMap file first, it then becomes corrupted and I can't open that file from my desktop anymore.

Comment: Convert your excel sheet to a geodatabase table, there is an excel to table tool in toolbox.

Comment: @Hornbydd I converted the table and it came out, but it still gives the same error when I try to load that table into the reclass tool. Just "Error. Error loading table."

Comment: @EricSimpson Close excel completely when you convert the excel sheet to geodatabase.